# After upgrading to latest Android Studio (1.5.1) android emulator hangs

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I upgraded Android Studio to 1.5.1 from 1.3 including the complete platform SDK. Since this upgrade my x86 Emulator started hanging. The emulator boots properly and Android starts up. The GUI works. But after a minute or two the emulator hangs completely without displaying any kind of error. Since this moment the emulator freezes completely and no interaction is possible. Are there any known issues with the new Emulator.exe? In the old version 1.3 of Android Studio/SDK I have never experienced this kind of problem.

My HAXM is configured to 2GB and I use the default AVD machine with 1536 MB (Android 6.0). My system has 8GB of memory running Win7 x64 using Intel Core 2 Duo CPU. I also tried to completely uninstall Android Studio/platform stuff and made a clean install of latest Android Studio but it did not resolve the problem. Did you experience similar issues as well with the higher than 1.3 version? What can I do to resolve it?

Thanks for any feedback!

best regards,
krompo

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem with a fresh install of android studio 1.5.1 on win 7 64-bit with only 3 gigs of RAM.

Comment: I just figured out that the hanging is not so random. It hangs after I install an app using Android Studio (using the "Run" command and starting the emulator). If I start the emulator itself without uploading the app it does not hang and works properly. May be the updated adb an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to uninstall android studio, download directly android studio 2.0 and install. Updating android studio via android 1.5 has issues with emulator due to default folder locations

Comment: But I have only 8 GB of RAM. Will that be sufficient for Android Studio 2.0 and the new Emulator? My motherbouard is rather old so I can not increase my ram to more than 8 GB. Have you tried working with AS 2.0 on an 8 GB  machine?